# Why do I need ifelse if I already have intent-filter in manifest file?

Tags: android, if-statement, android-intent, manifest, receiver

Ok, for example we have some code like [Trying to start a service on boot on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784441/trying-to-start-a-service-on-boot-on-android)
Why must I write ifelse in receiver for intent type validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be using the same receiver for multiple broadcasts, either:

- by having two `<intent-filter>` elements, or
- by having multiple actions for one `<intent-filter>` element, or
- by using the receiver for both implicit `Intents` (via the `<intent-filter>`) and explicit `Intents` (where the `Intent` identifies the Java class of the receiver)

In those cases, you might need to examine the incoming `Intent` to see which broadcast it is, so you know how to proceed.

In terms of that sample, though, I do not know why they have that `if` test. If they had an `else`, so they had two different bits of logic based on the `Intent`, it would make sense.